15 is red territory, Dredd movie
What is the meaning when Mama says 15 is red territory, in the movie Dredd?
She and Caleb are discussing expansion. But I don't know what being red is.

CALEB
The only danger is we expand too fast.
In the last few days we've added
distribution to three new blocks.
Pretty soon we'll be looking at making
inroads into sectors nine and fifteen.
MA-MA
Fifteen is still Red territory. Why
make waves?


Added a little more. Hard for me to transcribe exactly while on a cell.

David, thanks for the edit. Not sure if you are going off script or th like.  But movie is free on Prime, now. And the last part about why make waves is not in that movie.

I do think that part clarifies that she is concerned about pace. Which is implicit even from shorter version.

But I'm still not clear that red is Red Dragon.  After all she kicked their asses in Peachtrees. Wonder if red means something in larger context of Dredd universe.

I've read a great many Judge Dredd comics. I don't know of any meaning of Red .   And Ma-Ma, Peach Tree, Slo-Mo and Red Dragons were invented for the film, and weren't in the comic, AFAIK.  It seems to me that Red referring to a gang mentioned earlier is the most plausible meaning.

There's a quote in the movie, I think it's Dredd speaking, but this computer-generated transcript isn't clear. :

"Not so long ago there were three main gangs hustling for control of Peach Trees. The Peyote Kings, the Red Dragons, the Judged. Then Ma-Ma arrived."

So "Red territory" is territory controlled by the Red Dragon gang.
